# Searching a database based on a javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute a specific query where I search for the name that i get using javascript. I have this HTML:

```
<a onmouseover="showDef(textContent)" href="aLinkHere.com">myWord</a>
```

The function `showDef` gets the myWord and I'm trying to execute my query after that.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function showDef(txt) {
    var myWord = txt;
//Some code here to execute the query?
}
</script>
```

The query I want to have is as follows:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM defs WHERE name='myWord'");
```

Now I have to replace the 'myWord' with the word stored in the javascript variable. Is there any way to this? I already tried the following, but that didn't work..

```
document.write('<?php $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM defs WHERE name=\''+ myWord + '\'"); ');
```

I am relatively new in javascript and php, so any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is client side language and you need php (server side) lang to execute query.

Create ajax request with that variable and use that variable in your query. 
return that response from your remote php file and catch response in javascript. And enjoy with response.

IF you are searching name only(exact) then use `=` else use `LIKE` or `REGEXP` for better performance

This is an example that uses the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library.

```
    var dataString = 'searchVar='+ myWord;
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
           alert(data)
      }
});
```

IN php code you jst get variable with `$_POST['searchVar']` and execute your query

`$qry = "SELECT * FROM defs WHERE name LIKE '%".'$myWord."%'";`
and in while loop jst echo you response.

Comment: A little more depth would be useful.  A new user to JavaScript might not know what an AJAX request is, nor how to create one.

Comment: see above code above ajax.php is your remote php file. where you need to execute your query.

Answer (score 1):

You're relatively new indeed, this is basic strings 101.

1) do NOT use document.write, it's not meant for you to be used, it's an API from a decade ago and doesn't do what you think it does. Find the element you want to set the content of (using document.getElementById or the like) and then use .innerHTML = ... to set its content.

2) To get your value in your query on the PHP side, just put it in there, it's one of the basic features of PHP:

```
$myword = sanitize_the_hell_out_of_this($_POST['myword'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM defs WHERE name='$myword'");
```

You can pick whatever method you like for sanitization, there are a few baked into PHP but do NOT, under ANY circumstance, pass the posted value straight to your database, unless you like people deleting your database because they can. Someone can just edit the html, change the single word to "'; drop table words; 'lo" and now your table will get dropped. fun times =)

In order for it to actually work, remember your page runs on the client's computer, and PHP is a server technology. So the javascript will have to ask the server for the data by literally asking the server: you'll need an AJAX get or post operation, and then work with the data that get back. You can't inject PHP code and then have it run on the user's computer.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand don't edit my answer to include your own answer. Either comment or leave a second answer O_o (please move that comment out, I intentionally didn't cover how to do an AJAX request because there's a million ways to do so with a great number of libraries)

Comment: I felt it added something, but isn't an answer on its own.  Feel free to remove it.